# Extract non common areas between rasters in R

Tags: raster, r, spatial-analysis

I'm trying to extract the non common areas between two rasters in R.

I have two rasters: yellow and red.

I want to extract all the points of the yellow that do not overlap with red (i.e. all the yellow you see in the plot below).

I tried with the raster package but I got this error:

```
mask(crop(yellow, red), red)

Error in compareRaster(x, mask) : different extent
```

Here the extents:

```
extent(yellow)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 16.96877 
xmax       : 28.91172 
ymin       : 40.81715 
ymax       : 48.22444 

extent(red)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 16.74428 
xmax       : 28.91172 
ymin       : 40.23355 
ymax       : 48.89783
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use st_difference from the sf library, after converting to an sf object using st_as_sf()

Comment: First, please do not provide linked answers as URL's tend to disappear so, the answer cannot be archived. Second, this is not correct as sf does not support raster or terra objects and `st_difference` would not return the difference between the rasters. You could return the bounding geometry and return the difference in extents but, that is different than what the OP is after.

Comment: apologies, have edited